# Cannot gather attributes from span element using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfSNK.png) is an image of the source code I would like to parse from the following site (https://wwwn.cdc.gov/nchs/nhanes/search/datapage.aspx?Component=Examination) using BeautifulSoup. I wish to extract the attributes in the < span class='print-only'> attribute: the htm link.

My python code looks like so:

```
import urllib.request                                                                                                                                              

try:                                                                                                                                                
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup                                                                                                                          
except ImportError:                                                                                                                                                    
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  

url = "https://wwwn.cdc.gov/nchs/nhanes/search/datapage.aspx?Component=Examination"
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as page:
     html_source = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'html5lib')
link = soup.findAll("span", {"class":"print-only"})
```

Printing 'link' returns an empty list. I know there are span elements in the html code, because soup.findAll("span") returns html code (although no where in the contents of these span elements do I see a class called 'print-only').

**I noticed that the span attribute is greyed out in the Firefox developer window. A quick google search shows that this means the attribute is hidden. Does that mean it cannot be obtained with the method I am using?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the span element is hidden, you won't be able to retrieve it using BeautifulSoup. Maybe, you can use some other attribute to get the link you need. If you know the name of the .htm file you want to extract the link for, you can simply find the 'a' element (which is binding the required link and the hidden span element as well) using the inner text and just extract the 'href' from the element as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html5lib
import string

ascii = set(string.printable)
def remove_non_ascii(s):
    return filter(lambda x: x in ascii, s)


url = 'https://wwwn.cdc.gov/nchs/nhanes/search/datapage.aspx?Component=Examination'
home_url = 'https://wwwn.cdc.gov'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(url, headers = headers, allow_redirects = True)
soup = BeautifulSoup(remove_non_ascii(page.text), "html5lib")

link = soup.find_all('a', text='ARX_F Doc')[0]
complete_url = home_url + link.get('href')
print complete_url
```

Comment: This works! I wanted so badly to easily grab the span element, that I haden't considered using a different method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to get what you need using BeautifulSoup, first let's get the table:

```
table = soup.find("table",{'id':'GridView1'})
```

Now we find the `tr` tags in it's body:

```
>>> table.find('tbody').findAll('tr')[0]
<tr>
                <td class="text-center">
                    2009-2010
                </td><td class="text-left">Arthritis Body Measures</td><td class="text-center">
                    <a href="/Nchs/Nhanes/2009-2010/ARX_F.htm">ARX_F Doc</a>
                </td><td class="text-center">
                    <a href="/Nchs/Nhanes/2009-2010/ARX_F.XPT">ARX_F Data [XPT - 510.5 KB]</a>
                </td><td class="text-center">
                    September, 2011
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Notice the tag you were looking for is not there. I showed the first item of the list so you can analise better where's the url you need, as we can see, it's the first `a` tag we want, so for example:

```
>>> table.find('tbody').findAll('tr')[0].find('a')
<a href="/Nchs/Nhanes/2009-2010/ARX_F.htm">ARX_F Doc</a>
```

Now all that's left to do is to write a list comprehension to join all `href` attribute of the first `a` tag in each of the `tr` tags in a list:

```
>>> trList = table.find('tbody').findAll('tr')
>>> lst = [tr.find('a')['href'] for tr in trList]
```

If we print the first elements of `lst` we see this is our desired output:

```
>>> lst[:3]
['/Nchs/Nhanes/2009-2010/ARX_F.htm', '/Nchs/Nhanes/1999-2000/AUX1.htm', '/Nchs/Nhanes/2001-2002/AUX_B.htm']
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import urllib.request                                                                                                                                              
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup                                                                                                                             
url = "https://wwwn.cdc.gov/nchs/nhanes/search/datapage.aspx?Component=Examination"
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as page:
     html_source = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'html5lib')

link = soup.find_all("span", class_="print-only")
```

Comment: It looks like you are only changing how the class is identified? If so, I already tried that syntax to no avail.

Comment: 1) I had a typo - findAll vs find_all  2) I rewrote it to ensure bs4 is being used with bs4 syntax.